# how to check if a solid rectangular box is a subset of solid ball

Tags: subset

Suppose we have been given the coordinates of the centre of a solid rectangular box, the box's length, breadth, height and a solid ball with a given centre and radius.

Is there a ***fast*** way to check if the box is a subset of the ball? The only simple method that comes to my mind is to check if each of the 8 corner vertices lies inside the sphere. If yes, the box is indeed a subset of the ball (by convexity property of the ball).

Comment: I think that you answered your question.

Comment: I was asking for a faster method if it exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you expect that most of the time the box will not be inside the sphere, you can do some quick tests:

```
if (sphere.center.x+sphere.radius<box.center.x-box.size.x) return false;
if (sphere.center.x-sphere.radius>box.center.x+box.size.x) return false;
etc.
```

If you expect that the box will usually be far inside the sphere, you can do other quick tests:

```
bsx = box.size.x;
bsy = box.size.y;
bsz = box.size.z;
box_radius = sqrt(bsx*bsx+bsy*bsy+bsz*bsz)/2;
brx = box.center.x-sphere.center.x;
bry = box.center.y-sphere.center.y;
brz = box.center.z-sphere.center.z;
box_dist = sqrt(brx*brx+bry*bry+brz*brz);
if (box_radius+box_dist<sphere.radius) return true;
```

You will still need more precise tests if the quick tests fail though.

Answer (score 0):

There are only 4 corners to check, but in fact you only need to check 2 which are diagonal to each other.  This follows from the property of the rectangle having straight sides, while the circle is convex, as you state.

Alternatively, consider that if the left upper corner and right lower corner are both within the circle, then the rectangle they form is a [boudning box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_box).  The circle is obviously not, and thus the rectangle must be a sub-region of the circle.

**EDIT:** You might be talking about a box and a sphere, in which case the same idea applies, you just have to choose points which have different x, y, and z values